# "If one-to-many table has value" as column in SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one table with cars, and another table with fuel types.  A third table tracks which cars can use which fuel types.  I need to select all data for all cars, including which fuel types they can use:

Car table has Car_ID, Car_Name, etc

Fuel table has Fuel_ID, Fuel_Name

Car_Fuel table has Car_ID, Fuel_ID (one car can have multiple Fuel options)

What I want to return:

```
SELECT
    *
    , Can_Use_Gas
    , Can_Use_Diesel
    , Can_Use_Electric
FROM Car
```

The Can_Use columns are a BIT value, indicating if the car has a matching Fuel entry in the Car_Fuel table.

I can do this with multiple SELECT statements, but this looks painfully messy (and possibly very inefficient?).  I'm hoping there's a better way:

```
SELECT
    c.*
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Car_Fuel f WHERE f.Car_ID = c.Car_ID AND f.Fuel_ID = 1) AS Can_Use_Gas
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Car_Fuel f WHERE f.Car_ID = c.Car_ID AND f.Fuel_ID = 2) AS Can_Use_Diesel
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Car_Fuel f WHERE f.Car_ID = c.Car_ID AND f.Fuel_ID = 3) AS Can_Use_Electric
FROM Car c
```

Comment: You need to pivot the carfuel table and join the result of that onto car.

Comment: I don't understand - can you provide a code example, or explain more clearly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you have no duplicates in `Car_fuel`, so you don't need aggregation.  Hence you can do:

```
SELECT c.*,
       ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Car_Fuel f WHERE f.Car_ID = c.Car_ID AND f.Fuel_ID = 1), 0) AS Can_Use_Gas
       ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Car_Fuel f WHERE f.Car_ID = c.Car_ID AND f.Fuel_ID = 2), 0) AS Can_Use_Diesel
       ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Car_Fuel f WHERE f.Car_ID = c.Car_ID AND f.Fuel_ID = 3), 0) AS Can_Use_Electric
FROM Car c;
```

This is one case where `ISNULL()` has a performance advantage over `COALESCE()`, because `COALESCE()` evaluates the first argument twice.

Comment: I used ISNULL - apparently sql server doesn't have IFNULL.  Either way - it worked, thank you.

Comment: @steelerose . . . Ooops, I'm not sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score 3):

Although not a perfect solution, you could use the [pivot clause](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
select *
from   ( select     car_name, fuel_name
         from       Car
         inner join Car_Fuel on Car.car_id = Car_Fuel.car_id
         inner join Fuel     on Car_Fuel.fuel_id = Fuel.fuel_id
    ) as data
    pivot (
        count(fuel_name)
        for fuel_name in (Gas, Diesel, Electric)
    ) as pivot_table;
```

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b492a/11), which outputs a table like this:

```
| car_name | Gas | Diesel | Electric |
|----------|-----|--------|----------|
|   Jaguar |   0 |      1 |        0 |
| Mercedes |   0 |      1 |        1 |
|    Volvo |   1 |      0 |        1 |
```

The SQL statement still has the hard-coded list in the `for` clause of the `pivot` part, but when the number of fuel types increases, this might be easier to manage and have better performance.

#### Generating the SQL dynamically

If you use an application server, you could first execute this query:

```
SELECT stuff(   (   SELECT ',' + fuel_name
                    FROM Fuel FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 1, '') columns
```

This will return the list of columns as one comma-separated value, for example:

```
Gas,Diesel,Electric
```

You would grab that result and inject it in the first query in the `FOR` clause.

Answer (score 2):

I would suspect using counts would be inefficient as there would be a large number of sub queries running to total all the counts.

Below is an alternative using self joins. It's not as short as your example but may be easier to maintain and read and should be more efficient.

```
select car.car_id, car.car_name,
-- Select fuel variables 
CASE WHEN lpg.fuel_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS LPG,
CASE WHEN unleaded.fuel_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Unleaded,
CASE WHEN electric.fuel_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Electric,
CASE WHEN diesel.fuel_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Diesel
FROM car
-- Self Join fuel records
LEFT join car_fuel as lpg on car.car_id = lpg.car_id and lpg.fuel_id = 1
LEFT join car_fuel as unleaded on car.car_id = unleaded.car_id and unleaded.fuel_id = 2
LEFT join car_fuel as electric on car.car_id = electric.car_id and electric.fuel_id = 3
LEFT join car_fuel as diesel on car.car_id = diesel.car_id and diesel.fuel_id = 4
```

The self join will return a NULL if the car doesn't use that fuel type. The CASE returns 1 if the join found a record for that car/fuel and 0 if it didn't.

I hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

You could use conditional aggregation.

Do an outer join to the Car_Fuel table, and do a `GROUP BY` Car_ID to collapse the rows.

For each row from Car_Fuel, return a 1 if the Fuel_ID matches the one you are checking for, otherwise return a 0. And use a MAX() aggregate to filter the rows, finding out if any of them returned a 1.

For example:

```
SELECT c.Car_ID
     , c.Car_Name
     , MAX(CASE WHEN f.Fuel_ID=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Can_Use_Gas
     , MAX(CASE WHEN f.Fuel_ID=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Can_Use_Diesel
     , MAX(CASE WHEN f.Fuel_ID=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Can_Use_Electric
 FROM Car c
 LEFT
 JOIN Car_Fuel f
   ON f.Car_ID = c.Car_ID
GROUP
   BY c.Car_ID
    , c.Car_Name
```

With SQL Server, you'd need to repeat every non-aggregate expression in the `SELECT` list in the `GROUP BY` clause.  If you add more columns from the Car table to SELECT list, you'll have to copy those down to the GROUP BY.

If that's too painful, you could do the aggregation in an inline view instead, and then do the JOIN. To make sure a NULL doesn't get returned, you can replace a NULL value with a 0, in the outer query:

For example:

```
SELECT c.Car_ID
     , c.Car_Name
     , ISNULL(u.Can_Use_Gas,0)      AS Can_Use_Gas
     , ISNULL(u.Can_Use_Diesel,0)   AS Can_Use_Diesel
     , ISNULL(u.Can_Use_Electric,0) AS Can_Use_Electric
  FROM Car c
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT f.Car_ID
              , MAX(CASE WHEN f.Fuel_ID=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Can_Use_Gas
              , MAX(CASE WHEN f.Fuel_ID=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Can_Use_Diesel
              , MAX(CASE WHEN f.Fuel_ID=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Can_Use_Electric
           FROM Car_Fuel f
          GROUP BY f.Car_ID
       ) u
    ON u.Car_ID = c.Car_ID
```